# Validate a column on database level in PL SQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, validation, plsql

I have a requirement where I want to validate a column value which will be something like below.

- 1. It should be 18 characters in length.
- 2. It should not accept any special characters.

Below is the correct value for that column.

`INAPDNCHXXXXTW6002`

and the query for getting that value is below

```
SELECT RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID FROM NE.STRUCTURE WHERE RJ_SAPID = P_SAPID;
```

So, how can I do this in database level

Comment: Why do you need to do this in PL/SQL instead of, say, in a database constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check that value match your requirements, is to use regexp:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(col, '^[a-z0-9]{18}$', 'i') ;
```

If you want check that `RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID` column meets those requirements, you can use:

```
SELECT RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID FROM NE.STRUCTURE 
WHERE 
RJ_SAPID = P_SAPID 
and 
REGEXP_LIKE(RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID, '^[a-z0-9]{18}$', 'i');
```